# Android CursorAdapter not updating all fields

Tags: android, sqlite, simplecursoradapter

I have strange problem with my android app. I have some data and I saved that data in SQLite Database. And in this fragment I try to read my data from table using `SimpleCursorAdapter`

```
public class LogFragment extends Fragment{

    private static SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static SQLiteOpenHelper helper;
    private static Context context;
    private static ListView listView;
    private static String senderOrReceiver;
    private static SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = getActivity();

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.log_message, null,
                new String[]{Constants.COMMAND, Constants.VALUE, Constants.TIME_STAMP, Constants.MESSAGE_ID, Constants.SESSION_ID, Constants.PARAMS},
                new int[]{R.id.command, R.id.value, R.id.time_stamp, R.id.message_id, R.id.session_id, R.id.params}, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_log, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        if(db != null){
            db.close();
        }
    }

    public static void readFromDatabase(String sender){
        senderOrReceiver = sender;
        new DatabaseTalker().execute();
    }

    private static class DatabaseTalker extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Cursor>{

        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
            helper = new Database(context);
            db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
            return db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) {
            super.onPostExecute(cursor);
            adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

and here's what I got in my `ListView` . I have six fields (Command, Value, Time Stamp, MessageID, SessionID, Params) and as you can see only one field is filled (for example) `Command: On, Value: , Time Stamp: , MessageID: , SessionID: , Params: .` and so on... Why I get this result?

[image]

EDIT:

Here how I write my data to database

```
public void addInfo(Information info){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        addToTable(db, Constants.COMMAND, info.getCommand());
        addToTable(db, Constants.VALUE, info.getValue());
        addToTable(db, Constants.TIME_STAMP, info.getTimeStamp());
        addToTable(db, Constants.MESSAGE_ID, info.getMessageID());
        addToTable(db, Constants.SESSION_ID, info.getSessionID());
        addToTable(db, Constants.PARAMS, info.getParams());

        db.close();
    }

    private static void addToTable(SQLiteDatabase db, final String TAG, String value){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(TAG, value);
        db.insert(Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
```

Comment: How are you writing your data to the database?

Comment: @laalto I just have edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your each `addToTable()` call inserts a new row that contains just one column value.

To insert a row with all the values, add the values to the same `ContentValues` and call `insert()` once.